# Fetch schema fails with Apollo managed federation

Tags: graphql, nestjs, apollo, apollo-federation, apollo-studio

I integrate apollo managed federation with my apollo federation (gateway) with nestjs but when I run my gateway service I face with `CheckFailed: one or more checks failed` error.

I followed official document. but get the mentioned error. If anyone want my code, I will provide.
here is the error.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the error?

Comment: @greguintow could you please check it ?